# How to use multilayer neural network to predict next day energey consumption in r

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, mlp, autoregressive-models

The objective of this question is to use a multilayer neural network (MLP-NN) to predict the next
step-ahead (i.e. next day) electricity consumption for the 11:00 hour case. The first 430 samples will be used as
the training data, while the remaining ones will be used as the testing set.

[image of the energy consumption data. have 501 of these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9XTi.png)

Ok so i have no idea where to start. How do i determine the inputs? I have to use autoregressive model. Help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, your data represents a time series.
An MLP cannot be used successfully for this type of task.
There are other types of networks for Sequence Learning, including the so-called Vanilla RNNs.
I recommend that you take a look at this [link](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) to better understand how they work.